# Acumata Web Service Endpoint add Vendor Locations

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use a Contract API application to edit and maintain vendor Locations.

I'm slightly confused on how I add a detail to the web service endpoint. I can easily add fields, but it seems when I try to add a new element it's not actually loading anything.

Here is what I did:

1. Added Object with name "Locations" and type "Detail"
2. Under that, added a top level call "Location" with screen id "Customer Locations"
3. Added fields to that

I used this VB code:

```
                VendorFind = soapClient.Get(New Vendor With {.ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All,
                                            .VendorID = New StringSearch With {.Value = "V01026"},
                                            .Locations = New Locations() {New Locations With {.ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All}}})
```

It compiles and works but doesn't load the locations.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For your custom endpoint you might want to use the 'Populate' option on the web service endpoint screen  and select the required fields . Use the Vendor Location summary to get header information like vendor, location name etc and then select the details by selecting the correct mapped object for instance "General Info--> Location Contact " . This works fine and populates location details correctly for a selected vendor using postman tool . I am not much familiar with Vb but I suppose the issue might be in the way the endpoint entities are extended.